# Array de JQuery en prestashop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

Llevo un par de dias atascado con un script en prestashop. Necesito traer unos valores de la base de datos y los estoy haciendo mediante jQuery, ya que esos valores dependen de lo que haya seleccionado un usuario en la web.
El problema es que o no lo estoy haciendo bien, o luego no se acceder a los valores que trae el array.

He tratado de actualizar la llamada y ahora me da un error en consola(TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a)

Esta es la llamada al jquery:

```
<script languaje="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
/*Comprobamos si tiene localidad ya seleccionada*/
    function buscarProveedor()
    {
        var localidad=document.getElementById("localidad").value;
        var idLocalidad=document.getElementById("id_localidad").value;
        if(localidad)
        {
            /*Traemos todos los proveedores de esa localidad*/          
            document.getElementById("nombrelocalidad").innerHTML = localidad;
            var params = {
                "id_localidad" : idLocalidad
            };
            console.log('Aquí si entra');
            $.ajax({
                data: params,
                url: 'TraerProveedoresPorId.php',
                type:'post',                                                
                success: function(response){
                    $.each(response, function(index, data){                                         
                        $("#proveedor").append("<option value=" + data.name + ">" + data.name + "</option>");
                    });
                }           
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Debe seleccionar antes una localidad.");
        }
    }

    /*Cuando esté todo cargado ejecutamos la funcion que trae la localidad del producto*/
    window.onload = buscarProveedor();  
</script>
```

Y ahora el php que recibe el jquery hace la consulta:

```
<?php
    include '../config/config.inc.php';


    $variable = Tools::getValue('id_localidad');
    $query = "SELECT name FROM ps_supplier WHERE id_localidad ='" . $variable ." '";
    $id = Db::getInstance()->executeS($query);      
    echo $id;
?>
```

En el log de la consola me aparece este fallo:
[image: Error en consola]

Muchas gracias compañeros.

Comment: Si haces un `console.log(response)` en el success de la llamada ajax, que te devuelve?

Comment: He añadido el console.log() y muestro los datos, pero no se como capturarlos.

Comment: que hace la función p()

Comment: Se supone que muestra en prestahop las variables, pero tampoco lo consigo...

Comment: Si utilizas jQuery, ¿Para qué metes JavaScript puro? @jandresplp

Comment: Por que ya le estoy dando mil vueltas y no se por donde salir @Hoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final he conseguido dar con la solución despues de investigar.

```
<script languaje="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
/*Comprobamos si tiene localidad ya seleccionada*/
    function buscarProveedor()
    {
        var localidad=document.getElementById("localidad").value;
        var idLocalidad=document.getElementById("id_localidad").value;
        if(localidad)
        {
            /*Traemos todos los proveedores de esa localidad*/          
            document.getElementById("nombrelocalidad").innerHTML = localidad;
            var params = {
                "id_localidad" : idLocalidad
            };          
            $.ajax({
                data: params,
                url: 'TraerProveedoresPorId.php',
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $.each(response, function(index, data){                     
                        $("#proveedor").append("<option value=" + data.id_supplier + ">" + data.name + "</option>");
                    })
                }                       
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Debe seleccionar antes una localidad.");
        }
    }


    /*Cuando esté todo cargado ejecutamos la funcion que trae la localidad del producto*/
    window.onload = buscarProveedor(), asignarProveedor();

</script>
```

Y el php al que llama el jQuery me quedo así:

```
<?php
    include '../config/config.inc.php';


    $variable = Tools::getValue('id_localidad');
    $query = "SELECT id_supplier, name FROM ps_supplier WHERE id_localidad ='" . $variable . "'";   
    $id = Db::getInstance()->executeS($query);      
    echo json_encode($id);

?>
```

Espero le pueda servir de ayuda a alguien. Saludos compis.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a poner en el success

```
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    var element=response[i]
    //for(var key in element){
       console.log(element);
    //}
}
```

A ver si te muestra los datos.

Comment: Me sigue mostrando lo de arriba. El xmp

Comment: Y si intentas mostrar uno de los valores del objeto?? Acabo de modificar la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora me indica en la consola esto: 1358 undefined.

Comment: Es como si contará los caracteres de lo que devuelve  el JSON

Answer (score 2):

Amigo tu problema esta definivamente en el javascript. No obstante hay varias recomendaciones que pudiera hacerte de como trabaja Prestashop para que optimices tu codigo:

1. Solamente es necesario incluir este fichero: `include '../config/config.inc.php';`
2. Los valores de las variables pasadas por GET y POST se obtienen con la funcion: `Tools::getValue('id_localidad')`
3. Puedes eliminar: `p($id);`

Busca en el codigo original de Prestashop alguna llamada ajax con jquery para que veas como procesan los resultados.

Buena suerte.

Comment: Graciuas compañero. Voy a mirar a ver si veo como lo hacen. Muy interesante lo de Tools::GetValue.